# How to increment letters like numbers in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to write a function that takes in 3 characters and increments it and returns the newly incremented characters as a string.

I know how to increase a single letter to the next one but how would I know when to increase the second letters and then stop and then increase the first letter again to have a sequential  increase?

> So if AAA is passed, return AAB. If
>   AAZ is passed return ABA (hard part).

I would appreciate help with the logic and what php functions will be useful to use.

Even better, has some done this already or there is a class available to do this??

Thanks all for any help

Comment: I don't understand. AAA=>AAB but AAZ=>ABA. How do you decide which letters to increment? You said increment the second letters, so I take it you mean all but the first one? Shouldn't it be AAA=>ABB if you increment all but the first letter by one?

Comment: @Raoul Duke: it's base 26 with no numbers, just letters.

Comment: @Raoul - just run $X = 'AAA'; for($i = 1; $i < 1024; $i++) { echo $X++,'<br />'; } to see what is meant.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Character/string increment works in PHP (though decrement doesn't)

```
$x = 'AAZ';
$x++;
echo $x;  // 'ABA'
```

Comment: It's just a pity that $x-- won't work. @wimvds - thanks for adding the link

Comment: Or simply `echo ++$x;`  :)

Comment: as the documentation says decementing should work with $a-- : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: @TobiasGaertner - Decrementing __numbers__ works with `$a--`; decrementing __characters/letters__ does not... [example](https://3v4l.org/fsnu3)... and the docs page that you linked specifically says `Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented`

Comment: @Mark Baker - yes you are right - my mistake - just didn't wrote it carefully enough. Sorry

Comment: It was great help for me. Also we can increment alphanumeric i.e $x = 'AAA999'; $x++ results AAB000

Answer (score 24):

You can do it with the ++ operator.

```
$i = 'aaz';
$i++;
print $i;
```

aba

However this implementation has some strange things:

```
for($i = 'a'; $i < 'z'; $i++) print "$i ";
```

This will print out letters from `a` to `y`.

```
for($i = 'a'; $i <= 'z'; $i++) print "$i ";
```

This will print out lettes from `a` to `z` and it continues with `aa` and ends with `yz`.

Comment: It's not strange, it's just unintuitive. If `$i == 'z'` the condition is still true and `for` loop will continue, setting `$i` to `'aa'`. It's only when `$i` reaches `'za'` that the condition becomes false.

Answer (score 22):

### PHP 8.3+

You can now use native functions

[`str_increment()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-increment.php) and [`str_decrement()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-decrement.php):

```php
<?php
$str = 'ZA';
var_dump(str_decrement($str)); // 'YZ'

$str = 'AA';
var_dump(str_decrement($str)); // 'Z'
?>
```

---

As proposed in [PHP RFC: Strict operators directive](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/strict_operators):

> Using the increment function on a string will throw a TypeError when strict_operators is enabled.

Even though the RFC's state is Withdrawn, PHP will sooner or later go that direction of adding operator strictness. Therefore, **you should not be incrementing strings**.

## a-z/A-Z ranges

If you know your letters will stay in range a-z/A-Z (not surpass z/Z), you can use the solution that converts letter to ASCII code, increments it, and converts back to letter.

Use `ord()` a `chr()`:

```php
$letter = 'A';
$letterAscii = ord($letter);
$letterAscii++;
$letter = chr($letterAscii); // 'B'
```

1. `ord()` converts the letter into ASCII num representation
2. that num representation is incremented
3. using `chr()` the number gets converted back to the letter

*As discovered in comments, be careful. This iterates ASCII table so from `Z` (ASCII 90), it does not go to `AA`, but to `[` (ASCII 91).*

## Going beyond z/Z

If you dare to go further and want `z` became `aa`, this is what I came up with:

```php
final class NextLetter
{
    private const ASCII_UPPER_CASE_BOUNDARIES = [65, 91];
    private const ASCII_LOWER_CASE_BOUNDARIES = [97, 123];

    public static function get(string $previous) : string
    {
        $letters = str_split($previous);
        $output = '';
        $increase = true;

        while (! empty($letters)) {
            $letter = array_pop($letters);

            if ($increase) {
                $letterAscii = ord($letter);
                $letterAscii++;
                if ($letterAscii === self::ASCII_UPPER_CASE_BOUNDARIES[1]) {
                    $letterAscii = self::ASCII_UPPER_CASE_BOUNDARIES[0];
                    $increase = true;
                } elseif ($letterAscii === self::ASCII_LOWER_CASE_BOUNDARIES[1]) {
                    $letterAscii = self::ASCII_LOWER_CASE_BOUNDARIES[0];
                    $increase = true;
                } else {
                    $increase = false;
                }

                $letter = chr($letterAscii);
                if ($increase && empty($letters)) {
                    $letter .= $letter;
                }
            }

            $output = $letter . $output;
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

I'm giving you also 100% coverage if you intend to work with it further. It tests against original string incrementation `++`:

```php
    /**
     * @dataProvider letterProvider
     */
    public function testIncrementLetter(string $givenLetter) : void
    {
        $expectedValue = $givenLetter;

        self::assertSame(++$expectedValue, NextLetter::get($givenLetter));
    }

    /** 
     * @return iterable<array-key, array<string>>
     */
    public static function letterProvider() : iterable
    {
        yield ['A'];
        yield ['a'];
        yield ['z'];
        yield ['Z'];
        yield ['aaz'];
        yield ['aaZ'];
        yield ['abz'];
        yield ['abZ'];
    }
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't go from `z` to `aa` but to `{` and what not weird characters..

Comment: Hmm, good point, I have not ever gone so far. I've editted the answer. Giving feedback helps others too, thanks ;) I'll try to write working solution without incrementing strings and post it here anyway.

Answer (score 4):

To increment or decrement **in the 7bits 128 chars ASCII range**, the safest:

```
$CHAR = "l";
echo chr(ord($CHAR)+1)." ".chr(ord($CHAR)-1);
/* m k */
```

So, it is normal to get a backtick by decrementing `a`, as the [**ascii spec list**](https://ascii.cl/)

Print the whole **ascii** range:

```
for ($i = 0;$i < 127;$i++){
    echo chr($i);
}
/* !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ */
```

More infos about [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_character_set) [7 bits ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII): `man ascii`

---

To increment or decrement in the **8-bits extended 256 chars UTF-8 range**.

This is where it starts to differ regarding the host machine charset. but those charsets are all available on modern machines. From php, the safest is to use the `php-mbstring` extension: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php

> Extended ASCII (EASCII or high ASCII) character encodings are
>   eight-bit or larger encodings that include the standard seven-bit
>   ASCII characters, plus additional characters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

More info, as example: `man iso_8859-9`

```
   ISO 8859-1    West European languages (Latin-1)
   ISO 8859-2    Central and East European languages (Latin-2)
   ISO 8859-3    Southeast European and miscellaneous languages (Latin-3)
   ISO 8859-4    Scandinavian/Baltic languages (Latin-4)
   ISO 8859-5    Latin/Cyrillic
   ISO 8859-6    Latin/Arabic
   ISO 8859-7    Latin/Greek
   ISO 8859-8    Latin/Hebrew
   ISO 8859-9    Latin-1 modification for Turkish (Latin-5)
   ISO 8859-10   Lappish/Nordic/Eskimo languages (Latin-6)
   ISO 8859-11   Latin/Thai
   ISO 8859-13   Baltic Rim languages (Latin-7)
   ISO 8859-14   Celtic (Latin-8)
   ISO 8859-15   West European languages (Latin-9)
   ISO 8859-16   Romanian (Latin-10)
```

Example, we can find the `€` symbol in ISO 8859-7:

```
244   164   A4     €     EURO SIGN
```

---

To increment or decrement **in the 16 bits UTF-16 Unicode range**:

Here is a way to generate the whole unicode charset, by generating html entities and converting to utf8. [Run it online](https://3v4l.org/eHjAH)

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 262144; $x++){
  echo html_entity_decode("&#".$x.";",ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8");
}
```

Same stuff, but the range goes up to `(16^4 * 4)`!

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#33;',ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
/* ! */
echo html_entity_decode('&#34;',ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
/* " */
```

To retrieve [the unicode `€` symbol](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm),using the *base10* decimal representation of the character.

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#8364;',ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
/* € */
```

The same symbol, using the *base16* hexadecimal representation:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#'.hexdec("20AC").';',ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
/* € */
```

First 32 bits are reserved for [special control characters](https://ascii.cl/control-characters.htm), output garbage �����, but have a meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a number representation problem. This is base24 (or however many numbers your alphabet has). Lets call the base b.

Assign a number to each letter in alphabet (A=1, B=2, C=3).

Next, figure out your input "number": The representation "ABC" means `A*b^2 + B*b^1 + C*b^0`
Use this formula to find the number (int). Increment it.

Next, convert it back to your number system: Divide by `b^2` to get third digit, the remainder (modulo) by `b^1` for second digit, the remainder (modulo) by `b^0^ for last digit.

This might help: [How to convert from base10 to any other base](http://www.searchmarked.com/math/how-to-convert-from-base-10-decimal-to-any-other-base.php).

Comment: right. I can never really remember how many letters the alphabet has. It also depends on how you count (some people ommit "j" and "v" just doesn't seem like a real letter to me...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ASCII codes for alpha numerics. From there you increment and decrement to get the previous/next character.

You could split your string in single characters and then apply the transformations on these characters.

Just some thoughts to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
$values[] = 'B';
$values[] = 'A';
$values[] = 'Z';
foreach($values as $value ){
  if($value == 'Z'){ 
       $value = '-1';
    }
$op = ++$value;
echo $op;
}
?>
```

Comment: At least a bit of explanation would surely help the OP and further reader of your answer

Answer (score -3):

I have these methods in c# that you could probably convert to php and modify to suit your needs, I'm not sure Hexavigesimal is the exact name for these though...

```
#region Hexavigesimal (Excel Column Name to Number)
public static int FromHexavigesimal(this string s)
{
    int i = 0;
    s = s.Reverse();
    for (int p = s.Length - 1; p >= 0; p--)
    {
        char c = s[p];
        i += c.toInt() * (int)Math.Pow(26, p);
    }

    return i;
}

public static string ToHexavigesimal(this int i)
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    while (i > 26)
    {
        int r = i % 26;
        if (r == 0)
        {
            i -= 26;
            s.Insert(0, 'Z');
        }
        else
        {
            s.Insert(0, r.toChar());
        }

        i = i / 26;
    }

    return s.Insert(0, i.toChar()).ToString();
}

public static string Increment(this string s, int offset)
{
    return (s.FromHexavigesimal() + offset).ToHexavigesimal();
}

private static char toChar(this int i)
{
    return (char)(i + 64);
}

private static int toInt(this char c)
{
    return (int)c - 64;
}
#endregion
```

### EDIT

I see by the other answers that in PHP you can use `++` instead, nice!

Comment: This code is unnecessarily complex. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal#Conversion_algorithm_.28alphabet-only_system.29 for a simpler algorithm.