# Increment Letters: Weird Problem

Tags: php

I have just asked a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567180/increment-letters-like-numbers) and found out I can make use of `++` to increment letters. I have now tried this:

```
$last_id = get_last_id();

echo gettype($last_id); //string

echo 'L_ID ->'.$last_id.'<br />'; //AAF

$next_id = $last_id++;

echo 'N_ID ->'.$next_id.'<br />';//AAF
```

The following example which I was given works fine:

```
$x = 'AAZ';
$x++;
echo $x;//ABA
```

What is going on? Must be the end of the work day...

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

++ is a [post increment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php), thus

```
$next_id = $last_id++;
```

assigns the *current* value of $last_id to $next_id, and *then* increments it. What you want is a pre-increment

```
$next_id = ++$last_id;
```

Comment: Or he could break it into two statements: `$last_id++; $next_id = $last_id;`

Comment: Ah I did not know, that. Every time I ask a question on SO, it highlights how little I know about PHP! Thank you Paul.

Comment: @Abs: Also, these operators exist in a number of other languages, and their behaviour there is similar.

Answer (score 3):

Putting `++` after a variable will increment it when the statement it's part of completes. You're assigning to `$next_id` the value of `$last_id` before it's incremented. Instead, use `++$last_id`, which increments before the value of the variable is used.

Comment: That's not correct - the increment happens after evaluation, not when the whole statement completes. Thus $x=1; echo ($x++)*($x++); yields '2'

Comment: Also, operator precedence shows the order of evaluation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php