# Different formatting in PHP foreach function?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to print out a series of strings in a loop, modifying the string each iteration. Specifically, I want to add a letter into the string and with each iteration sequentially increment the letter through the alphabet.

For example if I run the foreach function below:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo "data-tax='".$term->name."'";
}
```

I would get something like

```
data-tax='apple'
data-tax='orange'
data-tax='banana'
```

However I want to add a letter into the string which increments each run yielding the following:

```
data-tax-a='apple'
data-tax-b='orange'
data-tax-c='banana'
```

How can I achieve this? I know I can add a letter into the string, but how can I move it through the alphabet?

Comment: `echo "data-tax-" . $variable_you_update . "'" . $term->name ."'"`

Comment: What should be the output if there are more than 26 terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increment letters/strings in PHP like you would numbers. So just use a letter like you would a counter and increment it each loop. See also: [Increment Letters like numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567180/increment-letters-like-numbers)

```
$letter = 'a';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo "data-tax-{$letter}='".$term->name."'";
    $letter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$l = 'a';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $tName = $term->name;
    echo "data-tax-$l='$tName'";
    $l++;
}
```

Please note that incrementing from `z` will result in `aa`, i.e.:

```
$letter = "z";
$letter++;
echo($letter);
//aa
```