# Autoincremented unique string id

Tags: php, mysql

I have read many answers on stackoverflow, but I haven't find anything related my issue.

This is my table:

```
`id` char(11) NOT NULL,
`element` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
```

I need to use an **autoincremented unique string id of 11 chars ( case sensitive if possible ) and numbers** as youtube does:

youtube.com/watch?v=**j5syKhDd64s**

youtube.com/watch?v=**YVkUvTmDf3Y**

youtube.com/watch?v=**8BcDeoKLsaY**

...

How could I do this with mysql/php ?

Comment: How can you increment a string?

Comment: @D4V1D The same way you could increment numbers. Heck, run-of-the-mill hexadecimal numbers are "incrementable strings": `FE + 1 = FF`.

Comment: @D4V1D aaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaab, aaaaaaaaaac, aaaaaaaaaad, ...

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567180/increment-letters-like-numbers

Comment: @deceze: No, hexadecimal numbers are hexadecimal numbers...

Comment: @waka Numbers are chains of arbitrary symbols in a defined order. I'm saying if hexadecimal numbers can contain A-F and can be incremented, then how hard is it to image "numbers" using A-Z which can be incremented?

Comment: @deceze: Look at what OP posted. How do you increment `8BcDeoKLsaY`? Ok, you could say "increment Y to Z", but after that? Is it "ba" at the end or "bA" or maybe it's "a1"?

Comment: Is the Youtube reference random, or is there a pattern to it? Is it just a hash of an integer for example?

Comment: @waka That's merely a problem of defining the desired behaviour, and it's pretty trivial. You know how to increment numbers when using the symbols 0-9, right? Just extend that alphabet used to `0-9a-zA-Z`. The rules about incrementation don't need to change at all. After 9 comes a, after z comes A, after Z you add a position to the "number" and wrap to 0.

Comment: @waka BTW, PHP already *can* increment strings: `$l = "Z"; var_dump(++$l); // AA`

Comment: @deceze: "After 9 comes a, after z comes A". Says who?

Comment: @waka My definition of my base 62 numbers. If you want to define your base 62 number alphabet differently or create an entirely different base, be my guest.

Comment: Something like `$id = rtrim(base64_encode(hash("crc32b", $num)),"=");` where `$num` is any integer, would generate 11 characters of upper, lower and digits: [Test here](https://eval.in/426071). Dunno if there's any collisions.

Comment: @deceze: Exactly. YOUR definition. But as far as I know there's no "official" definition that after "9" comes "a" (last time I checked, there was a 10 after a 9...) and after "z" comes "A". Therefore, "incrementing a string" is something that's really a matter of opinion, not a matter of facts.

Comment: @waka The *logic* of how a string can be incremented, i.e. how a value in a [positional numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) can be incremented, is very well defined and fixed. The only thing you need to do is to specify your alphabet. You seem to be questioning how a string could possibly be incremented at all, which is really a solved problem.

Comment: @waka And no, 10 doesn't come after 9 as far as a positional numeral notation is concerned. When incrementing 9, it wraps around to 0 and you increment the next position in your number.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like [hashids](http://hashids.org/). Their page also links to alternative solutions.

If that doesn't fit the bill, please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: it seems great but where can I put the last id to create the next row in mysql ?

Comment: You just use an integer auto incremented field for the id, and hash it for external use.

Comment: @user5287961 sorry I just noticed that it's not auto-incremented.

Comment: @Kickstart and for internal use ? Is there a reverse function to get the string from the id ?

Comment: The page given by user5287961 does talk about allowing decoding (and I would assume you will use a salt value to encode / decode them). But personally I would be tempted to store the encoded version on you database table as well.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to use this function

```
    function generateRandomString($length = 11) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

and then pass $randomString result to your query to add in DB.

EDIT :
 if OP is looking for the string like he mentioned `(aaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaab, aaaaaaaaaac, aaaaaaaaaad)` i recommend you to check out [Theory of Computation](http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc365/LN365_Lewis/L06-RegLangSol.htm) .

Comment: That's a terrible random string generator. `rand` is just about the worst random number generator you can choose. Use `/dev/random` to read a bunch of random bytes and simply convert them to a narrower alphabet. Base64 would be a decent choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which I Autoincremented my unique id string field.

```
case "Add":
    $itemno = $_POST['itemno'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $unitprc = $_POST['unitprc'];
    $amt = $_POST['amt'];
    $coopmemid = $_SESSION['kiosk']['is_coopmemID_kiosk'];
    $totamt = 0;
    $totitm = count($itemno);
    $a_empgroid = array();
    for($x=0; $x<$totitm; $x++) {
        $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount) 
                     VALUES ('$coopmemid',(NOW()),'$itemno[$x]','$qty[$x]','$unitprc[$x]','$amt[$x]')";
        $atecCoop->query($Addquery);
        $totamt+=$amt[$x];
        $inserted_id = $atecCoop->insert_id;
        array_push($a_empgroid,$inserted_id);
    }
    $Savequery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgroc_master (order_status, date_ordered, total_items, total_amount) VALUES ('Pending', (NOW()), '$totitm', '$totamt')";
    $atecCoop->query($Savequery);
    $empgrocmstid = $atecCoop->insert_id;
    $orderno = date('y-m-').str_pad($empgrocmstid, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $sql = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_no='$orderno' WHERE empgrocmstID='$empgrocmstid'";
    $atecCoop->query($sql);
    foreach($a_empgroid as $empgrocid) {
        $sql = "UPDATE tb_empgrocery SET order_no='$orderno' WHERE empgrocID='$empgrocid'";
        $atecCoop->query($sql);
    }
break;
```

As you can see the field `oder_no` is a unique id (varchar 25)

Hope this helps :)