# Generating Alphanumeric Codes in Sequence from AAA000 to ZZZ999

Tags: php, string, sequence, increment, alphanumeric

I needed to create a sequence of unique alphanumeric codes in PHP, starting from 'AAA000' and incrementing up to 'ZZZ999'. The codes should follow this pattern:

- From 'AAA000' to 'AAA999', then 'AAB000' to 'AAB999', and so on.
- After 'AAZ999', it should continue with 'ABA000' instead of 'ABZ000'.
- The final code should be 'ZZZ999'.

This pattern should give a total of 17,576,000 unique codes. I was initially unsure of how to handle the incrementation, especially when rolling over from 'AAZ999' to 'ABA000'. However, I've developed a solution in PHP that seems to work.

**My Current Solution:**

```
for($letter_code = 'aaa'; $letter_code < 'zzz'; $letter_code++){
    if($letter_code != 'zzy'){
        for($number_code = 0; $number_code <= 999; $number_code++){
            $code_str_number = str_pad($number_code, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $total_records_processed_count++;
            print (strtoupper($letter_code).$code_str_number."\n");
        }
    } else {
        // Handle 'ZZZ' after 'ZZY'
        for($number_code = 0; $number_code <= 999; $number_code++){
            $code_str_number = str_pad($number_code, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $total_records_processed_count++;
            print (strtoupper($letter_code).$code_str_number."\n");
        }
        for($number_code = 0; $number_code <= 999; $number_code++){
            $code_str_number = str_pad($number_code, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $total_records_processed_count++;
            print ("ZZZ".$code_str_number."\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**
I used a nested loop, the outer for the alphabetic part and the inner for the numeric part.
To handle the numeric part, I used str_pad to ensure the number always has three digits.
The special case for when $letter_code reaches 'zzy' is handled to include 'ZZZ'.

**Question:**
While this code works, I'm interested in knowing if there's a more efficient or elegant way to achieve the same result, particularly in handling the special case when the code rolls over from 'ZZY999' to 'ZZZ000'.

If anyone has any idea how I can better this question please leave me a comment and I will make amendments.

Comment: What do you want to get incrementing from aaa -> ???

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you, I saw. I marked up your answer. I didn't accept it as a solution though because your answer is only showing a better way to increment the values and not showing the process of generating the values. It's a great answer though. I like the solution. Very clean and concise!

Comment: @13g you aren't honestly planning on using a PHP script to do something 14 million times, right? What is your actual use case? If you are looping over some other data set, you declare a default of `'AAA000'` (or whatever the last used id was), then call this function to generate the next value at the end of each cycle.

Comment: @13g I'm not allowed to uv your question twice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP8.3 released `str_increment()` (and `str_decrement()`), all potential headaches with this task are eliminated.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5sE0E))

```
$tests = [
    'AAA000',
    'AAA999',
    'AAZ999',
    'AZZ999',
    'ZZY999',
    'ZZZ999',
];

foreach ($tests as $t) {
    echo "\n$t => " . str_increment($t);
}
```

Output:

```
AAA000 => AAA001
AAA999 => AAB000
AAZ999 => ABA000
AZZ999 => BAA000
ZZY999 => ZZZ000
ZZZ999 => AAAA000 <- throw a business logic exception if you like
```

---

To print a large amount of these alphanumeric values, it will probably be advisable to use a generator. For smaller volumes of data, simple loops will suffice.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bmE82))

```
function incGen(string $alnum = 'AAA000', string $stopBefore = 'AAAA000')
{
    if (!preg_match('/^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$/', $alnum)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid alnum value');
    }
    if ($stopBefore !== 'AAAA000' && !preg_match('/^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$/', $stopBefore)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid stopBefore value');
    }
    if ($alnum > $stopBefore) {
        throw new Exception('stopBefore cannot be reached by incrementation');
    }
    while ($alnum !== $stopBefore) {
        yield $alnum;
        $alnum = str_increment($alnum);
    }
}

foreach (incGen('AAA980', 'AAC123') as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

---

Related reading:

- [`str_increment()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-increment.php)
- [How to increment letters like numbers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3567180/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution, this will help you out.

```
<?php
for($i = 'aaa'; $i < 'zzz'; $i++){
  print "$i ";
} 
?>
```

Let me know if it not works for you or you need specific output.

Answer (score 0):

First of loop through the letters as they are the beginning of the code.

Then in your loop for the letters you can run through your numbers and merge the two to create your strings.

Here is a working solution for this functionality.

```
for($letter_code = 'aaa'; $letter_code < 'zzz'; $letter_code++){
    if($letter_code != 'zzy'){
// Reason for the if != 'zzy' is that I couldn't write <= 'zzz'
// This : <= 'zzz' breaks the loop.
        for($number_code = 0; $number_code <= 999; $number_code++){
            if($number_code > 99){
                $code_str_number = $number_code;
            }elseif($number_code > 9){
                $code_str_number = "0".$number_code;
            }else{
                $code_str_number = "00".$number_code;
            }
            $total_records_processed_count++;
            print (strtoupper($letter_code).$code_str_number."\n");
        }
    }else{
// Once reaching zzy we loop through zzy and then after do zzz
        for($number_code = 0; $number_code <= 999; $number_code++){
            if($number_code > 99){
                $code_str_number = $number_code;
            }elseif($number_code > 9){
                $code_str_number = "0".$number_code;
            }else{
                $code_str_number = "00".$number_code;
            }
            $total_records_processed_count++;
            print (strtoupper($letter_code).$code_str_number."\n");
        }
        $number_code = 0;
        for($number_code = 0; $number_code <= 999; $number_code++){
            if($number_code > 99){
                $code_str_number = $number_code;
            }elseif($number_code > 9){
                $code_str_number = "0".$number_code;
            }else{
                $code_str_number = "00".$number_code;
            }
            $total_records_processed_count++;
            print ("ZZZ".$code_str_number."\n");
        }
    }
    $number_code = 0;
    // For Testing Purposes just add this if() to cut the full loop 
    // if($letter_code == 'aab'){
    //  die();
    // }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a number `n`, the value of the last digit is `n % 10`. The remainder is `n - n % 10`. You can then right-shift the remaining digits by dividing by `10`.

Example:

- Lasts digit is `123 % 10 = 3`.
- Remainder is `123 - 123 % 3 = 120`.
- Right-shifted by one is `120 / 10 = 12`.
- Repeat for the remaining digits.

The important difference to your case is the way that the number is represented, it doesn't use a "normal" decimal system in particular. However, this is still a normal `integer` in PHP (which is binary), only that you don't use the default decimal output. What I mean here is that your approach to use a `string` as datatype for this is flawed. Instead, use an `integer` to represent the values from `0` to `17575999`, just use a different formatting.

For the formatting, let's adapt the above algorithm to this case. First thing is that the numeric system doesn't have a constant base. The last three digits are using base `10`. The digits before that use base `26`, with the digits being represented as uppercase Latin letters `A-Z`. `A = 0` and `Z = 25`. An additional small detail is that the output is zero-padded (or, rather, `A`-padded) to six digits.

Example:

- Start with the decimal number 12345.
- Last digit is `123456 % 10 = 6`, shifted remainder is `12345`.
- Next digit is `12345 % 10 = 5`, shifted remainder is `1234`.
- Next digit is `1234 % 10 = 4`, shifted remainder is `123`.
- Next digit is `123 % 26 = 19 = T`, shifted remainder is `4`.
- Next digit is `4 % 26 = 4 = E`, shifted remainder is `0`.
- Next digit is `0 % 26 = 0 = A`, shifted remainder is `0`.
- Remainder is now zero, so the conversion didn't overflow.
- Result is `AET456`.

Comment: For obvious reasons, this does not create a **sequence** of **unique** alphanumeric codes in **PHP**...

Comment: Care to elaborate, @Wimanicesir?