# how to generate unique referral code in php

Tags: php

I have created E-commerce website, In user system, I created referral system works like this -> **When a visitor create an account then unique referral code for that customer will be generated**. I fear that referral code should not be matched when I'll have a lot of users. So, I wanna create unique referral code.
**I am creating like this:**

```
$referral_code = strtolower(substr($first_name,0,3)).$this->refer_code(3);

public function refer_code($limit){
    return substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, $limit);
}
```

Here, I am picking first 3 letters from user name and 3 random letters. **It's generating referral code like this:**

```
illqhx
```

But my boss said that It's very difficult to read and tell to other. So, he wants that referral code should be only numbers or 3 letters from name and 3 numbers should be generated automatically and it should be unique, and limit should be 5 or 6.
Please help me

Comment: It is best to check in the database whether the generated code exists or not.

Comment: yeah i am putting that referral code in database already but i wanna generate code unique (only numbers or 3 letters from name and 3 numbers randomly generate)

Comment: Have you performed any collision analysis on this code? What are the statistical chances of two people having a similar name *and* the same code being generated? And as @AakashTushar mentioned you could just double check whether it already exists and re-generate if it does.

Comment: @ZainShabir For simplicity of coding and resulting readability, why not go sequential? 3 letters from name + 4 sequential digits, allows you to have 10000 customers of identical first name before you collide. But if instead of using numbers, use alphanumerical and you get an additional 26 possibilities -> 36^4 before you collide on the same first name. Sequantial or random doesn't really matter tbh.

Comment: How can i check brother?

Comment: I assume you have a check in place that checks whether a username/email is taken, account already exists? Same way, but on the referral code.

Comment: ohh, I got it, I'll do this thing but suggest me what should i do? I mean I am now checking that code exists or not and with this, I should then generate referral code only numbers or 3 letters from name and 3 numbers randomly?

Comment: @ZainShabir Actually, sharing of someone's profile as a link to the other wasn't meant to be readable. The tech behind it should be completely abstract for normal users.

Comment: Brother my boss said it should e remember-able, users can remember easily and can refer (tell) to others to create account from their referral code

Comment: @ThomasTimbul I can check that code exists or not but how can i tell system to regenerate other one then?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul like `if($referral_code === $dbmatched){echo 'code is same'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
function random_strings($length_of_string) 
{ 
    $str_result = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; 
    return substr(str_shuffle($str_result), 0, $length_of_string); 
} 

// This function will generate 
// Random string of length 10 
echo random_strings(10); 

?>
```

Comment: It's too much tough to remember for users

Comment: See updated code you can change the length of string that you need to generate

Comment: You can use any string like Captical `ABC` or small `abc` or `123`

Comment: I didn't get that variable $referral_code, It's not like that, That $referral_code variable and that line is in my other function of createAccount()

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding something like the following to your User class. You can use `createReferralCode` from the outside to retrieve the code. It will always return the same value. You could also just return `$this` and use an accessor method to retrieve the value.

How you save or validate your new key I'm leaving up to you.

```
/**
 * Referral Code
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $referralCode;

/**
 * Create a referral code and store it on the User.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function createReferralCode() : string
{
    if (empty($this->referralCode)) {
        // attempt to create a referral code until the one you have is unique
        do {
            $referralCode = $this->generateReferralCode();
        } while (!$this->hasUniqueReferralCode($referralCode));

        $this->referralCode = $referralCode;
    }

    return $this->referralCode;
}

/**
 * Generate a referral code.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function generateReferralCode() : string
{
    // generate crypto secure byte string
    $bytes = random_bytes(8);

    // convert to alphanumeric (also with =, + and /) string
    $encoded = base64_encode($bytes);

    // remove the chars we don't want
    $stripped = str_replace(['=', '+', '/'], '', $encoded);

    // get the prefix from the user name
    $prefix = strtolower(substr($this->firstName, 0, 3));

    // format the final referral code
    return ($prefix . $stripped);
}

/**
 * Check if the referral code is unique.
 *
 * @param  string  $referralCode
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function hasUniqueReferralCode(string $referralCode) : bool
{
    // check against database to enforce uniqueness
}
```

Comment: You're probably using an EOL version of PHP. You can remove those.

Comment: EOL means? I am using `7.2.6` version

Comment: End-of-life. Odd, that's a feature of 7.*. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Answer (score 0):

```
if($referrelid){
    $condition = ' AND username LIKE "' . $referrelid. '" ';
    $sql = $db->getRecFrmQry("SELECT ewallet FROM " . DB_TBLPREFIX . "_mbrs WHERE 1 " . $condition . "");
    $ewallet = $sql[0]['ewallet'] + 50;
    $data =array(
        'ewallet' => $ewallet,
    );
    if (count($sql) > 0) {
         $update = $db->update(DB_TBLPREFIX . '_mbrs', $data, array('username' => $referrelid));
    }
}
```

When the new user creates an account with any refferel id, $50 added to his account when the account is created successfully.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your referrer code to be only numbers, perhaps generating a unique code is not the best idea. Instead you can save the code in a database, start from `000001` and work your way up.

In this case you're guaranteed to have unique codes since you know all the previous codes.

This could also work with alphanumeric characters using the same principle. But starting with `000AAA` or something similar.

Leaving aside the guaranteed non collision you can also keep track of issued referrer codes and invalidate them at will using a column such as `is_active`.

---

Concrete example from your code:

Lets assume that client Dave has referrer code `illqhx`. Lets also assume that client Linda wants a referrer code too.

Your code may look something like this:

```
// get dave's referrer code from the database
$dave_referrer_code = 'illqhx';
$linda_referrer_code = $dave_referrer_code++;
var_dump($dave_referrer_code); // illqhx
var_dump($linda_referrer_code); // illqhz

// Do note that this code won't work, it's just an example
```

What you should actually do is get the column with the largest id from the database, get the referrer code from there and increment that.

Having a `unique` index on the `referrer_code` column will guaranteed uniqueness since you can't have duplicate codes.

It makes much easier as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I am saving referrals code in database already, column name is `referral_code`, I just wanna create unique referral code

Comment: Currently, your codes are strictly letters, correct?

Comment: Yeah, it's only letters

Comment: You should stick to letters then. PHP can actually [increment letters too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567180/how-to-increment-letters-like-numbers-in-php). So overall my approach would still work. But you'll most likely get codes such as `AAAAAA`, `AAAAAB` etc. Not exactly the end of the world but some people may not like it. It's up to you. The major advantage here is that you're guaranteed uniquness for any given code, since you can compare it with the rest of the codes easily.

Comment: I didn't get how can i do this as you are telling me the way

Comment: yeah it's fine but it's not what i am looking for