# check if number remaining zero if divided by 2 and 3

Tags: php

how to achieve the following table in excel or HTML.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|a   |b   |c   |a   |b   |c   |a   |b   |c   |a   |b   |c   |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

EDIT FOR REAL CASE:

So I want to print `Rit`, `Liter`, and `Volume` respectively in ms Excel for about 15 times. let say `Rit` will occupy column E1, `Liter` on F1, `Volume` G1..repeat 15 times.

heres is my code so far:

```
$i = 0;
$j = 1;
foreach($this->cellRange('E', 'AY') as  $col){
    if($i % 3 == 2){
        if($j > 15){
            $sheet->setCellValue($col.'5', 'Total');
        }else{
            $sheet->setCellValue($col.'5', $j);
        }
        $sheet->setCellValue($col.'6', 'Volume');
        $j++;
    }else if($i % 2 == 1){
        $sheet->setCellValue($col.'6', 'Liter');
    }else{
        $sheet->setCellValue($col.'6', 'Rit');
    }

    $i++;
}
```

`$this` refer to current object (Laravel controller), while `$sheet` refer to PHPExcel sheet object.

Comment: The loop you showed will loop 11 times (not 12 as you apparently want), but it does nothing more than loop.  Can you edit the code to show where you're attempting to print output?

Answer (score 0):

After edit:

Since you're using `$this->cellRange('E', 'AY')` to loop over your range, you can keep track of a counter (like you've already got).

However, instead off using modulus, I would just create a hard-coded check, something like so:

```php
<?php

$i = 0;
foreach($this->cellRange('E', 'AY') as  $col){

    // Handle 1/2/3
    switch ($i) {
        case 1:
            $sheet->setCellValue($col.'5', 'Total');
            break;

        case 2:
            $sheet->setCellValue($col.'6', 'Volume');
            break;

        case 3:
            $sheet->setCellValue($col.'6', 'Rit');
            break;
    }

    // Add 1 to $i, If ($i === 3), start over by setting to 1
    $i = ($i === 3) ? 1 : ++$i;
}
```

---

Before edit:

We can use PHP's ability to [increment characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567180/how-to-increment-letters-like-numbers-in-php/51629190) so simplify this like so:

```php
<?php

for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
    for($c = 'a'; $c <= 'c'; $c++){
        echo $c;
    }
}
```

```
abcabcabcabc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLKy2/SEMlU8FWwcBaAUjb2CoYgxja2prVXApAAJZPBsqrJ6oDJZJBKtSTwUy4GhBITc7IB4pZgwVquWr//wcA)

---

We could also use PHP's [`range()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to generate a range for us.

```php
<?php
$res = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
    $res = array_merge($res, range('a', 'c'));
}

echo implode('', $res);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYoxCoAwEAT7e8UVQgxaCJZRfIiIBI1GUHOclYhvjxew2tmdJU8xNh15gozdhS32g4ElcJ5tUiqDkk2LdYKi0A/g/7PM9h4Px6vL01Qi21NYWVWimpTWBl4AN/mA20F7mMWJSl9tYvwA)

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post, however I made edits to reflect my current issue. please kindly check updated post.