# How to increment complete string in php?

Tags: php, string, increment

How to increase a complete string in php. Like `abc` should be converted to `bcd`.
I tried

```php
$i="abc";
$i++;
echo $i; //abd
```

But it increases only the last character.

I searched many question like this but I did not find any solutions.

Comment: so if it works for one character, maybe try a **loop** and increment every character?

Comment: What would you expect xyz to be converted to? z by default will increment to aa, but if you want it to rotate to a instead you'll need to do something different.

Comment: Sir how to increment a string by two or three eg i want to conert hi to "jk

Comment: @Azad What is your actual question? You seem to be posting a different question and looking for a different answer?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have read [How to increment letters like numbers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567180/how-to-increment-letters-like-numbers-in-php/51629190).

However, the `$i++` only works on a single char.

---

So to get the desired output, we could simply:

1. Convert the string into an array using [`str_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)
2. Loop over them using a [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) , change, or in my case create a new output

   1. 'Increase' the char using `++`

```php
<?php

$test = 'abc';
$output = '';

foreach (str_split($test) as $char) {
    $output .= ++$char;
}

echo $output;
```

The above code will produce:

```
bcd
```

as you can [try in this online demo](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAgEEX3c4pZCBpBFzDpKGFiTBA46LSKzm4i@HfvPx4T17puTAygJBZBh9ofQVtQ6RF@@tEIzpSjD4SmSN4L35eYHkzoC6pAPk/4AraNcHE4z91Y@ABioDScrfUH).

---

A more compact solution would involve

- [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) as a loop
- A [short function notation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)
- [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to stitch back the array to a string

```php
<?php

$test = 'abc';
$result = implode(array_map(fn ($c) => ++$c, str_split($test)));

echo $result;
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxLCoAgEADQ/ZxiFkJK3cA@RxEzQ8FyUFt0@omi7Vs8CsQ8LhQIQDRfG07Y2dV1GkTx9UovxINS3ry0pdjbHJbkfqIUTuE0Y98LN2BtxVRKsclvUUppAO9Cxr/RzA8)

Comment: Sir how to increment a string by two or three eg i want to conert hi to "jk

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by the following 3 steps:

1. Convert each character to an unsigned integer, by using php's built-in function  [ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php).
2. Increment this integer by one (or by other number).
3. Convert it back to character (using php's built-in functon [chr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)).

```php
$test = 'abc';
$output = '';

foreach (str_split($test) as $char) {
    $output .= chr(ord($char)+1);
}

echo $output;
```

[See demo](https://tio.run/##NYvBCoQwDETv@YocCrYIwp6r@ClLzVaysNCQxtPit1dRnNvMmycsrY2zsAA4y9Vwwi4t1EVwZTPZruFssBbNiRh9NX1X@X3NX0LAVNERJw34BzzziMOExOqLfvzN@1eIsANk4vK8YmsH)

Comment: Sir how to increment a string by two or three eg i want to conert hi to "jk"

Comment: @Azad: Make an effort, you have the solution in front of you!

Comment: Just replace number 1 in `$output .= chr(ord($char)+1);` with another number eg 2.

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).